# How to run ASP.Net Core 5 WebApi project platform target x86 on windows container

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, containers

I have Asp.net core 5 webapi microservice comminicate with unmanaged C++ (32bit) code.
C++ DLL code can be run only on Windows OS.
I have configured my project x86 platform target and define Windows docker.
When run applicaltion/microsrivice without Docker everything work fine.
I guess that default docker configuration doesn't suite, because x86 platform configuration.
Attempts to resolve issue:

1. I have tried to configurate docker file with : --runtime win-x86 or --runtime win10-x86, but it failed.
2. I have tried to configurate RID according to Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog

Steps to reproduce issue:

1. Create Empty Asp.net WebApi core 5 project with docker support checkbox
2. From the project properties set "Platform Target" to x86
3. Open Project file .proj and set "Windows"

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Services/Calculation/Calculation.API/Calculation.API.csproj", "Services/Calculation/Calculation.API/"]
COPY ["Services/Calculation/Calculation.Application/Calculation.Application.csproj", "Services/Calculation/Calculation.Application/"]
COPY ["Services/Calculation/Calculation.Domain/Calculation.Domain.csproj", "Services/Calculation/Calculation.Domain/"]
COPY ["Services/Calculation/Calculation.Infrastructure/Calculation.Infrastructure.csproj", "Services/Calculation/Calculation.Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Services/Calculation/Calculation.API/Calculation.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/Calculation/Calculation.API"
RUN dotnet build "Calculation.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build 

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Calculation.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish 

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Calculation.API.dll"]
```

Comment: What error are you receiving / experiencing?

Comment: Output window: 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.5\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[1648] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -532462766 (0xe0434352).